# Spatialite does not use gpkg_spatial_ref_sys in GPKG mode

Tags: spatialite, geopackage, sqlite

Spatialite and GPKG mode are enabled:

```sql
SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite');
SELECT EnableGpkgMode();
```

Spatialite knows about `gpkg_spatial_ref_sys` ([`gpkgInsertEpsgSRID()` uses it](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=4.2.0+functions#8)), and the table
is populated:

```
sqlite> SELECT srs_name, srs_id FROM gpkg_spatial_ref_sys;
Undefined cartesian SRS|-1
Undefined geographic SRS|0
WGS 84 geodetic|4326
Amersfoort / RD New|28992
```

Yet when I try to use `ST_Transform()` it tries to look for (and fails to find) `spatial_ref_sys`:

```
sqlite> SELECT ST_Transform(gpkgMakePoint(5.140743, 51.630698, 4326), 28992);
unknown SRID: 4326      <no such table: spatial_ref_sys>
unknown SRID: 28992     <no such table: spatial_ref_sys>
Error: ST_Transform exception - unable to find the origin SRID.
```

What am I doing wrong? Does GPKG mode not support `ST_Transform()`? What is `gpkgInsertEpsgSRID()` for then?

Version info:

```
sqlite> SELECT spatialite_version(), sqlite_version();
5.0.1|3.34.1
```

Comment: SpatiaLite works internally on SpatiaLite geometries. For using the functions you must a) cast GPKG geometries into SpatiaLite geometries (happens to some extent automagically) and b) have all SpatiaLite support tables available. You need to execute also `InitSpatialMetaData`. `gpkgInsertEpsgSRID()` needs to be there because GPKG is not valid without GPKG metadata tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184) says it is in fact necessary to have a separate `spatial_ref_sys` table. However, instead of using `InitSpatialMetadata()` and getting many other tables, the following SQL seems to have worked as well (for `ST_Transform()` at least).

```sql
CREATE TABLE spatial_ref_sys (
  srid       INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  auth_name  VARCHAR(256),
  auth_srid  INTEGER,
  srtext     VARCHAR(2048),
  proj4text  VARCHAR(2048)
);
INSERT INTO spatial_ref_sys SELECT
  srs_id AS srid,
  organization AS auth_name,
  organization_coordsys_id AS auth_srid,
  definition AS srtext,
  NULL
FROM gpkg_spatial_ref_sys;
```

Comment: That is a good minimal solution. There is a "mode" switch in InitSpatialMetadata https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html that control what happens but at least geometry_columns table is created by the same.

Comment: thanks so much for this! i think i need to make a little script to run every time i enter the sqlite shell with a geopackage...the list of junk to "turn on" to be functional is becoming too long to remember.